# How to specify case-insensitive rule with rewrite middleware?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core

I have the following:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRedirect("home/(.*)", "/$1")
    .AddRedirect("Home/(.*)", "/$1")
    .AddRedirect("downloadics/(.*)", "ics/$1")
    .AddRedirect("DownloadICS/(.*)", "ics/$1");
```

I would like to have it so that the I can just have one entry for home and one entry for download ics and have it not be case sensitive.

I tried passing `(?)` to the front of the regex but it seems to blow up on that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can make these regular expressions case-insensitive by adding a `(?i)` at the very beginning. This adds the `i` flag which generally means “case insensitive”:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRedirect("(?i)home/(.*)", "/$1")
    .AddRedirect("(?i)downloadics/(.*)", "ics/$1");
```

Comment: Didn't work for me using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite

Comment: @GeorgeFilippakos That’s not really a good problem description… What exactly does not work? Do you have other rewrite rules that are working properly, but just the case-insensitive ones aren’t? Do the rules work with any special casing?

Comment: @GeorgeFilippakos check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60573568/why-does-asp-net-cores-url-rewriting-middle-ware-does-not-match-following-regex