# Why does asp.net core's URL Rewriting middle ware does not match following regex?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite simple url to other url in asp.net core 3 application. I have used the re-writer as follows

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite(@"^(?i)quote_request.aspx\?id=(.*)", "quote/revise/$1", skipRemainingRules: true));
```

But this is not matching and rewriting (mysite)/quote_request.aspx?id=123 to (mysite)/quote/revise/123

Am I missing something? Regex matches perfectly at https://dotnetfiddle.net/vk0ZVn though.

also,

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite(@"^(?i)quote_request.aspx(.*)", "quote/revise$1", skipRemainingRules: true));
```

is correctly rewriting (mysite)/quote_request.aspx?id=123 to (mysite)/quote/revise?id=123.

Comment: are there any errors or logs that you have access to?

Comment: No, there are no errors and I am just starting with this Re-writer middle-ware so haven't configured any logging yet. First rule just doesn't match, which according to my understanding, should match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to look into code of `RewriteRule` in order to find answer. Here is fragment of `ApplyRule` method:

```
PathString path1 = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
Match match = path1 != PathString.Empty ? this.InitialMatch.Match(path1.ToString().Substring(1)) : this.InitialMatch.Match(path1.ToString());
if (!match.Success)
    return;
```

`context.HttpContext.Request.Path` returns only `/quote_request.aspx` for request to `quote_request.aspx?id=123` while missing part is in `context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString`! So it just ignores part of url after `?` and doesn't apply rule even if passed regex is correct. So in order to do avoid skipping query you have to write custom `IRule` based on existing `RewriteRule` class, here is simplified example:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;

public class CustomRewriteRule : IRule
{
    public Regex InitialMatch { get; }

    public string Replacement { get; }

    public bool StopProcessing { get; }

    public CustomRewriteRule(string regex, string replacement, bool stopProcessing)
    {
        InitialMatch = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        Replacement = replacement;
        StopProcessing = stopProcessing;
    }

    public virtual void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var fullPath = context.HttpContext.Request.Path + context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
        var match = fullPath != string.Empty ? InitialMatch.Match(fullPath.Substring(1)) : InitialMatch.Match(fullPath);
        if (!match.Success)
            return;

        var str = match.Result(this.Replacement);
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        if (StopProcessing)
            context.Result = RuleResult.SkipRemainingRules;

        request.Path = str[0] != '/' ? PathString.FromUriComponent("/" + str) : PathString.FromUriComponent(str);
        request.QueryString = QueryString.Empty;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions().Add(new CustomRewriteRule(@"^(?i)quote_request.aspx\?id=(.*)", "quote/revise/$1", true));
app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, much appreciated. I suspected this. I wonder what is the motive behind just using path and ignoring query string in default implementation of re-writer .

Comment: Also, I was trying to exactly match case insensitive "quote_request.aspx" with @"^(?i)quote_request.aspx$". But it was not matching. Do you have any idea why it was not matching?